# Cuando publico en Github pages no reconoce los estilos, imagenes ni script

Tags: html, css, github

Como dije en el titulo y despues de ver otras consultas similares, resulta que no encuentro el error. Subo mi proyecto a Github pages y no me reconoce el archivo estilos.css ni las imagenes, ni el script. En VSC, live server sale todo bien. Ya he visto sugerencias de rutas relativas pero he modificado una y otra vez y no encuentro la solucion. Agradecería muchisimo una mano. Como verán soy nuevo en Git. Mil gracias.

https://github.com/riosmario/curriculum

https://riosmario.github.io/curriculum/

Es mi primer consulta. Sepan disculpar si me falta enviar informacion. Gracias.

Comment: Parece que deberías quitar la / delante de las rutas (para el css y el js, y el ../ en el caso de la primera imagen, las demás las está cargando bien). En todo caso, la consola de desarrolladores del navegador te permitirá ver los errores que el navegador está encontrando a la hora de cargar tu página.

Comment: Como bien te indica @abulafia, el problema está [aquí](https://github.com/riosmario/curriculum/blob/master/index.html#L10) y [aquí](https://github.com/riosmario/curriculum/blob/master/index.html#L156) por usar una ruta absoluta y [aquí también](https://github.com/riosmario/curriculum/blob/master/index.html#L28) por usar una ruta relativa a un directorio padre que no tiene un subdirectorio llamado `img`. Te he enviado una petición de fusión con los cambios para que la aceptes: https://github.com/riosmario/curriculum/pull/1

Comment: A grandes rasgos, en el servidor en vivo de VSC la raíz del sitio web es la raíz de tu repositorio, pero en github pages tu página está metida en un subdirectorio con el nombre del proyecto (`curriculum`), de modo que si no usas rutas relativas correctamente tu sitio web dejaría de funcionar cuando lo movieras de ruta.

Comment: Hola Mario, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: Fantástico! Muchas gracias!